# Mean of a censored Poisson random variable

Tags: r, random-variable, poisson-distribution, censoring

Consider a real demand estimation problem of a retailer where matrix $Y$ (contains Poisson random variables) is the real demand and its mean need to be estimated by using sales data (matrix) $X$ which is bounded by stock (matrix) $C$.

$\lambda_{ij}= E[Y_{ij}]$ so in matrix form $Y=[Y_{ij}]_{i\leq N, j\leq T} $ and 
 $\Lambda= [\lambda_{ij}]_{i\leq N, j\leq T}$

$X_{ij}=min(Y_{ij},C_{ij}) $ is the censored $Y$

I am trying to code following function $f(\lambda,C)$ in R.

Could someone help me to find a way to do that or at least help me to simplify $f(\lambda,C)$?

Ref: [Amjad and Shah (2017)](https://sdsc2017.mit.edu/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Muhammad_Amjad.pdf)

[image]

Where

```
X=matrix(data=seq(0,9),5,6)

C=matrix(data = seq(1,10),5,6)

and m is each entry of M
```

What I tried to write some code based on [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/179426/how-to-derive-the-mean-and-variance-of-a-k-truncated-poisson) , but I am not sure if it is correct;

```
func <- function(X,C){

  lambda <- colMeans(X)



  qk <- function(C) {C - ppois(C, lambda=lambda)}


  lambda * qk(C-1) / qk(C)

}
```

Ref: [Amjad and Shah (2017)](https://sdsc2017.mit.edu/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Muhammad_Amjad.pdf)

Comment: Given the relation between Poisson and Gamma variables, expect a relatively simple solution in terms of an [incomplete Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) (proportional to the CDF of the Poisson variable).  Indeed, one formula for natural numbers $C$ is $$f(\lambda,C)=C - \frac{1}{C!}\left((C-\lambda)\Gamma(C+1,\lambda) + \lambda^{C+1}e^{-\lambda}\right).$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The best way to implement a formula is first to analyze it,** because often the way in which it is expressed *theoretically* is not a good way to *compute* it.  To that end, let's split the sum into two parts:

$$\lambda - f(\lambda,C) = \sum_{t=C}^\infty (t-C) \frac{\exp(-\lambda) \lambda^t}{t!} = e^{-\lambda}\sum_{t=C}^\infty t \frac{\lambda^t}{t!} -  e^{-\lambda}\sum_{t=C}^\infty C \frac{\lambda^t}{t!}.$$

For natural numbers $C,$ both of these already look very much like the tail probability for a Poisson$(\lambda)$ variable $X,$

$$S_\lambda(C) = \Pr(X \gt C) =\sum_{t=C+1}^\infty \Pr(X=t)= e^{-\lambda}\sum_{t=C+1}^\infty \frac{\lambda^t}{t!}.$$

Comparing these to the sums in the first formula leads us to re-express them as

$$e^{-\lambda}\sum_{t=C}^\infty t \frac{\lambda^t}{t!} = e^{-\lambda}\sum_{t=C}^\infty \lambda \frac{\lambda^{t-1}}{{t-1}!}  = \lambda e^{-\lambda}\sum_{t=C-1}^\infty \frac{\lambda^{t}}{{t}!} = \lambda S_\lambda(C-2)$$

and

$$e^{-\lambda}\sum_{t=C}^\infty C \frac{\lambda^t}{t!} = CS_\lambda(C-1),$$

whence

$$\lambda - f(\lambda,C) = \lambda S_\lambda(C-2) - CS_\lambda(C-1).$$

We should worry a little bit about subtracting one potentially large value from another, which can lose precision, and manipulate this result further to obtain

$$ f(\lambda,C) = \lambda\left(1 - S_\lambda(C-2)\right) + C S_\lambda(C-1) = \lambda F_\lambda(C-2) + C S_\lambda(C-1)$$

where $F_\lambda$ is the Poisson distribution function $F_\lambda(t) = \Pr(X \le t).$  This is a sum of positive values and so will not suffer catastrophic loss of precision.

---

**Any statistical computing platform will provide facilities for quickly and accurately computing $F_\lambda$ and $S_\lambda.$**  For instance, an `R` function to compute $f(\lambda,C)$ is

```
f <- function(lambda, C) {
  C <- ceiling(C)
  lambda * ppois(C-2,lambda) + C * ppois(C-1, lambda, lower.tail=FALSE)
}
```

(It uses `ppois`, which is [implemented with an incomplete Gamma function `pgamma`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Poisson.html).  See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) for more.)

Test `f` through comparison to the brute force summation, such as this quick and dirty implementation based on the definition of $R$.

```
.f <- Vectorize(function(lambda, C) {
  C <- ceiling(C)
  i <- 0:ceiling(qpois(1 - 1e-15, lambda))
  sum(pmin(i, C) * dpois(i, lambda))
})
```

Because it sums $O(\lambda)$ terms, it will be inefficient for large $\lambda,$ but that's okay for testing.

A test will compute many values with both functions and study the differences between their outputs, *up to reasonably anticipated floating point roundoff error.*  Here's a quick example that also times the two functions:

```
lambda <- 2000
C <-  0:ceiling(qpois(1 - 1e-15, lambda))
system.time(a <- f(lambda, C))
system.time(b <-.f(lambda, C))

e <- zapsmall(c(1, b-a))[-1]
plot(a, e)
```

(The plot shows all the errors are zero.)  The benefits of the analysis are clear: where `f` takes no measurable time, `.f` takes about one second.

---

By the way, replacing a variable $Q$ with $R = \min(Q,C)$ is neither "censoring" nor "truncation" in the usual meanings of those terms:

- **Censoring** would replace $Q$ with a *category,* often written "$\ge C$," whenever $Q \ge C.$  It's usually incorrect to code that category numerically as equal to $C,$ which is what the variable $R$ is doing: that produces biased and often erroneous results when standard procedures are applied.
- **Truncation** would remove all data where $Q \ge C.$  The only possible observations would be the values $0,1,\ldots, C-1.$

Here is an illustration of the distinction.  It plots the distribution functions for a truncated, censored, and "censored/truncated" Poisson variable $X$ with $\lambda=7$ and $C=6.$  The left "Truncated" plot attains its maximum value of $1$ by the time $X$ reaches $6$ to reflect the fact that all possible values of $X$ are strictly less than $6.$ The middle "Censored" plot has no values at $6$ and greater because with censoring *we simply don't know* how the distribution continues.

[image: Figures]

It is worth knowing these distinctions lest you be led astray by (mistakenly) applying procedures for truncated or censored variables to $R.$